# Setting the value of a form input in a Leaflet popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have a draggable marker and want to update a form input with the new LatLng when the marker is moved.

On first load, the Popup html includes

```
<input type="text" id="newLatLng" name="newLatLng" value="">
```

The drag event is

```
marker.on('dragend', function(e) {
    console.log('dragend'); 
    newLatLng = marker.getLatLng().lat + ' ' + marker.getLatLng().lng;
    console.log(newLatLng);
    $('#newLatLng').val(newLatLng);
 });
```

The console log shows that the drag event and the correct values are being fetched, but the input value is not being set.

Any pointers welcome - I can't help feel I've missed something obvious!

Comment: Did you investigate how html code looks like after popup initialization? Maybe the real `input` is hidden and some wrapper is used for showing up popup.

Comment: Are you using pure leaflet or using any supporting library like MApBOX...

Comment: @Regent good point. But it looks OK `<input type="text" id="newLatLng" name="newLatLng" value="">`

Comment: @CrazyAboutJavascript no general library at all, but a few plugins. Can't think of anything that would affect this

Comment: @Regent here's the full list of nested divs and IDs/classes:
#map .leaflet-map-pane .leaflet-objects-pane .leaflet-popup-pane .leaflet-popup.leaflet-zoom-animated .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper .leaflet-popup-content form#markerForm input#newLatLng

Comment: @jamesinealing can you form it with appropriate formatting in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? But it is also important to check what styles are applied to these elements, especially for `newLatLng`.

Comment: @Regent thanks. Yes, of course, but I'll have to do that later today as I just posted this quickly in my lunch hour ;) I should have said though, the form is appearing perfectly in my popup and displays an empty input for newLatLng

Comment: @jamesinealing ok. I don't know whether you can create full example (so that we can test problem) or not, but right now it all looks not good at all for debugging: `input` is shown (as you said) and its value is not set (even though `$('#newLatLng').val(newLatLng);` is deadly correct).

Comment: @Regent I've just done a deploy to a public site for testing.  Apologies for terrible state of code, and overall 'rough' design! Go to http://postcodepast.com/#lat=51.48384582900783&lng=-0.2950724959373474&zoom=19 Click the question marker. Click any image. A new dragable marker and popup is created and you will see the form. Click Move and drag the new red marker. This is the event that should change the value in the form, to set newLatLng. The code is around line 150 on /assets/js/app.js. Note the Confirm button won't work as I haven't set up the db on the server as yet. Thanks :)

Comment: @Regent I am not sure if this helps, but I just tried switching to pure Javascript with `var newLatLngInput = document.getElementById('newLatLng');
newLatLngInput.value = newLatLng;
` and I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null ` from the second line

Comment: @jamesinealing most probably your code is executed before popup is recreated. To check this idea wrap your current `$('input[name="newLatLng"]').val(newLatLng);` with `setTimeout` with about 5 seconds delay and check the result. Full line code: `setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="newLatLng"]').val(newLatLng); }, 5000);`

Comment: @Regent YES! That's it. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it? Of course the question still remains how I can set this so that it is triggered on an event rather than having to use a timeout, although I guess one thing I could do is find a 'safe' interval and display a loading symbol and/or have it make the Confirm button live. Thanks so much for persevering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executed before popup is recreated. To check this idea you can wrap your current `$('input[name="newLatLng"]').val(newLatLng);` with `setTimeout` with about 5 seconds delay and check the result. Full code:

```
setTimeout
(
    function()
    {
        $('input[name="newLatLng"]').val(newLatLng);
    }, 
    5000
);
```

Even though this code only for testing, you can use this idea to create workaround for problem by setting timeout for small period of time, checking for `input` existance, and if it hasn't existed yet, wait some more. Something like this:

```
(function check()
{
    if ($('input[name="newLatLng"]').length)
    {
        $('input[name="newLatLng"]').val(newLatLng);
        ... other related logic
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(check, 200);
    }
})();
```